# Drag and Drop feature for HTML multiple select box

Tags: javascript

Can anybody let me know is there any way to implement the drag and drop functionality for multiple select box using pure javascript.

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/accessible-drag-drop/

Comment: There is a lot you can do with drag/drop in jqueryUI https://jqueryui.com/.

Comment: I have to do this only with pure javascript.

Comment: Can you use HTML5?

Comment: No. We don't use HTML5.